# Android Studio JDK name wrong

Tags: java, android, git

I am contributing to an android project, using android studio as an IDE. For some reason my android studio's JDK name is 'Android API 22 Platform (1)' and the other contributor is 'Android API 22 Platform' (stored in the app.iml file) every  time I have to update my branch this has to be changed. Is there a way to change the name of the JDK to 'Android API 22 Platform' so it is the same.

Many thanks in advance. Also should I just git ignore the .iml files?

Comment: You should definitely gitignore .iml files and anything else generated by Android Studio. The project will always be able to be recreated from the Gradle files.

Comment: @var47 's comment should be an answer - actually, The answer.

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio will automatically generate project files that are specific to your particular workspace environment.  Generally, these shouldn't be checked into version control because they will cause conflicts with other developers like you're currently experiencing.

I use the following .gitignore file when starting a new project.  This should keep almost all transient Android Studio workspace files out of your Git repo.

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.ap_

# Files for the Dalvik VM
*.dex

# Java class files
*.class

# Generated files
bin/
gen/
build/

# Gradle cache files
.gradle/

# Local configuration file (sdk path, etc)
local.properties
/local.properties
/.idea/workspace.xml
.idea/
*.iml

# Log Files
*.log

# OS-specific folder attributes
.DS_Store
Thumbs.db
```